# No error with extern keyword while having multiple definitions

Tags: c++, c, linker-errors

I have the following code segment main.c and below is the file somefile.h

```
#include "somefile.h"
extern int var = 10000;

int main()
{

    cout << var << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and somefile.h  contains

```
int var;
```

My question is when I execute this code it produces output 10000, but why this not a redefinition error. Since I assume `extern int var = 10000;` is definition.  Also now if I assign some value to `var` in somefile.h it gives me an error saying redifinition which is as expected. I am using VS 2010.

Comment: What is "assign some value to var in somefile.h " ? You mean inside a function in somefile.h? (Assignments cannot occur outside of functions)

Comment: GCC 4.7 raises a redefinition error

Comment: @MattMcNabb somefile.h only contains only one statement i.e int var;

Comment: My question was, what did you mean when you said "assign some value to var"?  `int var;` is not an assignment (nor is it a statement either).

Comment: @MattMcNabb if I run the above code it gives output as 10000 but if in somefile.h I make int var = 100; instead of int var; it gives me an error **C2374: 'var' : redefinition; multiple initialization**

Comment: That's correct for C (see my answer)

Comment: @MattMcNabb also if I write `extern int var = 1000` outside main i.e global it is fine. if at all keeping the above code same if I write `extern int var = 1000` in main it gives **error C2205: 'var' : cannot initialize extern variables with block scope**.

Comment: That's correct again.

Comment: Why did you tag the question with both C and C++?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I thought that the extern behaviour would be same for C and C++. But the answers here have clarified me now.

Answer (score 3):

This question is tagged C and C++, but those are different languages. My answer is about C.

If your code contains, at file scope, the sequence `int var;  /* ... */ int var = 10000;` then this is legal in C.

The line `int var;` is called a **tentative definition**, it is a wee bit like a forward declaration of a function, but for a variable.  If there is a subsequent definition of the variable, that definition supersedes it; otherwise the tentative definition counts and the variable will be initialized to `0`.

Your `extern` keyword makes no difference as variables defined at file scope are `extern` anyway unless you specifically use the `static` keyword.

However, if you added a second translation unit that `include`s somefile.h, then the behaviour is undefined. That is because two different translation units both define the variable `var`.  Your linker may diagnose this but the C standard does not require it to.

If you give an initializer to the line in somefile.h, e.g. `int var = 5000;` then this is a multiple definition error that your compiler must diagnose.

Comment: Tentative definitions can also be used with arrays, e.g. `int x[];  /* ... */   int x[10];` If there is no full definition afterwards then the array has a size of `1`.

Comment: And C++ doesn't have tentative definitions, cf. https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fdata_dec.htm, so "int var;" is a complete definition and thus "extern int var = 10000" is a redefinition.

Comment: Edited my answer to clarify I'm talking about file scope. At block scope (e.g. inside a function) there are no tentative definitions, that code is a multiple definition error.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I tried `int var;  /* ... */ int var = 10000;` in a simple C program on ideone.com using C compiler but it does gives an error as multiple declaration.

Comment: Then either their compiler is broken or you were using it wrong, can you link directly to the example?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the OP didn't shape his example the way he did in order to discuss tentative definitions. Perhaps one should state the underlying ideas, apart from language lawyer stuff, and for both C and C++:

- **All this is only important if you have multiple "translation units"**, i.e. c/cpp files which are compiled separately and then linked together in a separate step (this may happen behind the scenes if you use an IDE like VS).
- You want to make variables which are used in several units known to them without having multiple definitions. The difference is named *"declaration"* (i.e. making known) vs. *"definition"* (i.e. creating the variable proper by creating and initializing storage). Oscar Wilde at customs *declared* "nothing but his genius", but *defined* it in books and conversations.
- The "making known", i.e. the declaration, usually happens by means of header files. That's just convenience: The compiler proper doesn't know anything about headers but translates a concatenated sequence of code, consisting of all headers and the source which includes them. With exactly the same result **one could just copy/paste the header file into the c file at the place of the #include directive,** no magic involved whatsoever. That's crucial to understand.
- **The making known, the *declarations* of globals are prefixed "extern",** indicating that the definition may be extern to the translation unit (and remember, the translation unit here is the concatenation of all headers and the c file). No initial value is given; the variable is initialized elsewhere, when it is created.
  (The definition *may* be in the same translation unit as we'll see. That's ok, the extern declaration is then just redundant, but must match.)
- Globals must be created and initialized, i.e. *defined*, exactly once, usually in a c/cpp file of your choice. **The definition does not belong in a header file.** That's because headers are meant to be included by several c files which would lead to multiple attempts to create the same object.

I created a mini prog from your example with two source files to demonstrate the idea. The second c file contains a function which will be used in main.c. Both c files include the same header file. The header file provides a mutual information exchange: Both c files know which resources (variable, function) the other one provides. Including the header also ensures that the definitions in the c files match the declarations which the others see.

The header file itself doesn't create anything.

**somefile.h**

```
// make var known to whoever it may concern: 
extern int var;    // declaration, nothing created

extern int computeHalfVar(); // declare a function
```

**halfVar.c**

```
// The header contains the declaration of var
// which is defined in main.c
#include "somefile.h"

int computeHalfVar() { return var/2; }
```

**main.c**

```
#include <iostream>

// declares computeHalfVar() which we'll use 
#include "somefile.h" 

using namespace std;

// create and initialize var.
// This is the variable everybody else will use.
// The type must match the declaration in the header.
int var = 10000;   

int main()
{
    cout << var << endl;

    // Use a function defined in a different translation unit.
    // The compiler knows the name and signature from the header we included.
    cout << computeHalfVar() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not simply a redefinition error. It is "C274: 'var' : redefinition; multiple initialization" error. So actually it is multiple initialization. If you consult Microsoft documentation it clearly states:

The identifier is initialized more than once.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88cc602k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx